Product over all fibers
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a terminal object $\operatorname{pt}$. Let's say we have some objects fibered over some object $B$, i.e. a morphism $f: A \to B$.
First of all, I'm interested in the following construction:
Let $\operatorname{pts}(B) = \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{pt}, B)$. For each $b \in \operatorname{pts}(B)$, we can take the following pullback:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\require{HTML}
\newcommand{\rotate}[2]{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(#2deg)}{#1}}
\begin{CD}
P_{f, b} @>p_A>> A \\
@VVV @VVfV \\
\operatorname{pt} @>>b> B \\
\end{CD}
$$
For example, if $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{Set}$, we have $P_{f, b} = f^{\leftarrow}[\{b\}]$.
This induces a map
$$
\coprod_{b \in \operatorname{pts}(B)} P_{f, b} \to A
$$
Question 1: Under which conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ is this map an isomorphism?
Second of all, I would now like to take essentially a product over all fibers, i.e. define
$$
\mathscr{P} \left( \begin{CD} A \\ @VVfV \\ B \\ \end{CD} \right) = \prod_{b \in \operatorname{pts}(B)} P_{f, b}
$$

This is clearly functorial in $A$: If $g: A_1 \to A_2$ is a morphism with $f_1 = f_2 \circ g$, we get two commutative diagrams
$$
\begin{CD}
P_{f_1, b} @>p_{A_1}>> A_1 \\
@VVV @VVf_1V \\
\operatorname{pt} @>>b> B \\
\end{CD}
\qquad
\begin{CD}
P_{f_2, b} @>p_{A_2}>> A_2 \\
@VVV @VVf_2V \\
\operatorname{pt} @>>b> B \\
\end{CD}
$$
Combining these yields a commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{*9c}
& & & & P_{f_2, b} & & \overset{p_{A_2}}{\rightarrow} & & A_2 \\
& & & & & & \overset{g}{\rotate{\rightarrow}{-22}} & & \\
P_{f_1, b} & & \overset{p_{A_1}}{\rightarrow} & \rotate{\rightarrow}{112} & A_1 & & & \rotate{\rightarrow}{112} {\!\!\! \scriptstyle f_2} & \\
& \rotate{\rightarrow}{45} & & & & \rotate{\rightarrow}{45} {\!\! \scriptstyle f_1} & & & \\
& & \operatorname{pt} & & \underset{b}{\rightarrow} & & B & & \\
\end{array}
$$
We see that we have a morphism of the diagrams of which we take the pullbacks. This induces a map of the pullbacks:
$$
\begin{array}{*9c}
& & & & P_{f_2, b} & & \overset{p_{A_2}}{\rightarrow} & & A_2 \\
& & \overset{\tilde{g}_b}{\rotate{\dashrightarrow}{-22}} & & & & \overset{g}{\rotate{\rightarrow}{-22}} & & \\
P_{f_1, b} & & \overset{p_{A_1}}{\rightarrow} & \rotate{\rightarrow}{112} & A_1 & & & \rotate{\rightarrow}{112} {\!\!\! \scriptstyle f_2} & \\
& \rotate{\rightarrow}{45} & & & & \rotate{\rightarrow}{45} {\!\! \scriptstyle f_1} & & & \\
& & \operatorname{pt} & & \underset{b}{\rightarrow} & & B & & \\
\end{array}
$$
Collecting the $\tilde{g}_b$ induces a map
$$
\tilde{g}: \prod_{b \in \operatorname{pts}(B)} P_{f_1, b} \to \prod_{b \in \operatorname{pts}(B)} P_{f_2, b}
$$
i.e. a map
$$
\tilde{g}: \mathscr{P} \left( \begin{CD} A_1 \\ @VVf_1V \\ B \\ \end{CD} \right) \to \mathscr{P} \left( \begin{CD} A_2 \\ @VVf_2V \\ B \\ \end{CD} \right)
$$

However, note that this construction is not functorial in $B$.
Question 2: Does this construction $\mathscr{P}$ have a common name?

Please do not answer in the comments, @NaïmFavier.

For an affirmative answer to Question 1, you probably should assume in the first place that $\coprod_{b\in\mathrm{pts}(B)}\mathrm{pt}\rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism. Indeed, this is just the desired conclusion for $f=\mathrm{id}_B$. Now, if $B$ satisfies this condition, the affirmative answer to Question 1 for all $f$ with target $B$ is equivalent to this coproduct being universal. In many categories (like $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Set}$), all coproducts are universal, so oftentimes this condition on $B$ is the only obstruction.
That said, the condition on $B$ is very much non-trivial. For example, consider $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Top}$ (coproducts in this category are universal). The condition on $B$ is equivalent to $B$ being a discrete topological space, which is very restrictive. For another example, consider $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Ab}$ (more generally, any pointed category), then the condition simply asks for $B$ itself to be the zero object. In fact, in this case (assuming $\mathcal{C}$ admits kernels), you can check that your conclusion holds for an individual $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ if and only if it is the zero morphism between these two objects.
I have no suggestion for Question 2.
